# Problem compiling ar_pose (openCV fatal error)

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, ros, catkin

I'm getting an error when trying to compile ar_pose, as part of ar_tools in ROS noetic under Ubuntu 20.04.

When running catkin_make:

```
In file included from /home/alveybj/catkin_ws/src/ar_tools/ar_pose/src/ar_multi.cpp:25:
/home/alveybj/catkin_ws/src/ar_tools/ar_pose/include/ar_pose/ar_multi.h:47:10: fatal error: opencv/cv.h: No such file or directory
   47 | #include <opencv/cv.h>
```

Do I need to downgrade ROS? Ubuntu? Somehow tell ROS where my openCV libraries are? Thanks for any help!

Update: I was able to get ar_tools to compile correctly in ROS melodic using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with WSL2. Not sure why this wasn't working in Noetic, maybe OpenCV has been updated?

Comment: Looks like you need to install libopencv-dev: [https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-20-04/](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

Comment: Unfortunately I've already installed that library! I'll try following the rest of that tutorial though and report back. Thanks

Comment: Followed the tutorial in the link posted by @drescherjm above but still running into the error.

pkg-config --modversion opencv4 
returns 
4.2.0

Comment: you might have to _upgrade_ ROS. it tries to use ancient deprecated and removed **C API** of OpenCV. that hasn't been available for a while now. ROS is lagging behind.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz ROS Noetic is the most recent version. OP is having this issue because what they're trying to build was was only officially supported on ROS distros from 2014, not what they're trying to run on.

Comment: @BTables That's correct. I updated the post above. I was able to get things working by downgrading Ubuntu and ROS to 18.04 and Melodic respectively.